# Arduino delay only in one part of the code

Tags: c++, arduino, delay, fade

Hello i am new to stackoverflow. I have a problem

```
    if (brightness2 == 0 || brightness2 == 255) {
    fadeAmount2 = -fadeAmount2 ; 
  }  
  // wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect    
  delay(30);
```

and

```
Serial.println((byte)tempC);   
  delay(1000);
```

the second delay affects the first and the led fade is much more slow.
My question is how can I apply a delay to only one part of the code and another to another.
Hope you understood what i mean. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the second delay **after** the fade has completed.

Comment: the second delay will delay the whole code so it is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But you can count to 33:

```
static int cnt = 0;

if (brightness2 == 0 || brightness2 == 255) {
    fadeAmount2 = -fadeAmount2 ; 
}

delay(30);
cnt = (cnt + 1) % 33;
if (cnt == 0) {
    Serial.println((byte)tempC);
}
```

This will make the fading work as fast as before, **and** the printing will fire every once in 990 milliseconds.

Comment: and why should i count to 33?

Comment: @Chris because `1000 / 30 = 33`.

Comment: isn't there another way for example to create another void and aply delay in there ?

Comment: @Chris You could set up another timer and use its interrupt routine for one of the actions (the fading or the printing).

Answer (score 0):

In the examples, 02. Digital, there is a blink without delay example.  You should be able to modify this to work for your application.